# Is Oauth2 supported by Microsoft Identity Manager

Tags: oauth-2.0, identity, claims-based-identity, identity-management

We have a bunch of websites under re-built and few mobile apps under development. We are looking for a Identity Manager / Server that can be used for authentication and authorisation of the users logging into those portals and apps. I did some a brief research but could't find the answer to my questions below:

1. Does't MIM support OAuth2 / OpenId Connect based authentication protocol?
2. Can we create user profile and add users claims in it?
3. Does it have APIs that portals can call to add users into the user storage?
4. Does it provide API endpoints for change password and forgot password to add self serve password recovery feature on the portals?

I am a developer and have little knowledge about active directory and identity management area.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same boat you are in, and was trying to decide between MIM and Red Hat Keycloak.  I ended up going with Keycloak, it is powerful yet easy to setup, configure, and manage, whereas MIM is a pain in the neck to setup.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.  When you get enough reputation you will be able to comment.

Comment: Did MIM offer the same features as offered by Keyclock? I was looking for for a product from Microsoft stable as all our sites are built with .net. Finally we went ahead with Identity Server v3.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for a single signon or federation solution, if that's the case MIM won't be able to help you.  MIM is designed to synchronise user accounts from an authoritative source and maintain them in other connected systems (typically HR to AD).

The equivalent product to Keycloak in the Microsoft space would be ADFS (Active Directory Federation Services) or Azure AD.